# How do I get the output of an execute stored procedure action in Logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I'm executing a stored procedure and getting a large json output but how do I assign the output to either a variable or csv table etc? I'm trying to send the output as an email attachment.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ9w4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the body of `Execute stored procedure (V2)` from the `dynamic content`:

[image]

You can click on `Add new parameter` and select `Attachments`, Then put the variable value in the `Attachments Content`：

[image]

Comment: thanks got it working. parsed the json too. sorry total noob question